# How to move HERE watermark on left or right corner in HERE Maps SDK Android

Tags: android, here-api

Below is the sample screenshot like how currently the watermark is appearing:
[image]

I want to move this watermark to the left/right corner inside of the map.

Comment: How are you placing the watermark? Please post your code

Comment: I am not placing this watermark manually. It is a default logo, similar like Google logo at the bottom of Google Map's screen. I am just loading a fragment `class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.SupportMapFragment"`. You can find sample code [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/dev_guide/topics/app-create-simple.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using HERE Premium SDK, Should be possible using SupportMapFragment ->   setCopyrightLogoPosition (https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/content/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/SupportMapFragment.html#setCopyrightLogoPosition-com.here.android.mpa.common.CopyrightLogoPosition-)